# If $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic and $|f(z)| \geq 1 \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$, show $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

> If $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic and $|f(z)| \geq 1 \space \space \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$, show that $f$ is constant

I have attempted to prove this, but I am not sure if my proof is correct. I tried to follow the proof of Liouville's Theorem to do this:

Since $f$ is holomorphic, by Taylor's Thm, we have that $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $R>0$,

$$f'(z)  = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{|w-z|=R} \frac{f(w)}{(w-z)^2} dw$$ Now using the estimation lemma, $$\left|f'(z) \right|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \oint_{|w-z|=R} \frac{|f(w)|}{R^2} |dw|$$ Then

$$\left|f'(z) \right|\leq -\frac{1}{2\pi R^2} \oint_{|w-z|=R} -\space|f(w)| |dw|$$ $$\leq-\frac{1}{2\pi R^2} \oint_{|w-z|=R} 1 |dw| = -\frac{1}{R}$$

Letting $R\rightarrow \infty$, we have $f'(z) = 0 \space \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$, i.e. $f$ is constant.

Is this correct?

Comment: You don't need to do anything like that. A solution is very short. Do you know that bounded entire function is constant?

Comment: Hint : Consider $1/f$. What does Liouville's Theorem says about that ?

Comment: @edm I think OP knows that, since he or she is precisely trying to adapt the proof of that theorem.

Comment: Your proof is not correct. You're basically proving that the modulus of something is negative, which obviously can't be right.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Ok, so where is the fault?

Comment: You have the wrong inequality when going from the line before the last to the last (and you've also forgotten a sign, which explains the problem I pointed out above). $\oint_{|w-z|=R} -\space|f(w)| |dw|\leq \oint_{|w-z|=R} -1 |dw|$ is correct, but if you multiply that by a negative number you change the sense of the inequality.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Ah, I then get $\frac{1}{R}$ and letting $R\rightarrow \infty$ gives the result?

Comment: No, you get something like $\left|f'(z) \right|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \oint_{|w-z|=R} \frac{|f(w)|}{R^2} |dw|\geq \frac{1}{R}$, and you can't say anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simpler proof:

$|f(z)| \geq 1$ implies $f(z)\ne 0$ for all $z$.
Therefore, $g(z)=\dfrac{1}{f(z)}$ is an entire function.

Since $|g(z)| \leq 1$ for all $z$, Liouville's Theorem says that $g$ is constant and so is $f$.

Comment: ok wow, that is much better. Is mine correct though?